# Sending sensor data from dragino lora transmitter to dragino lora receiver using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, lorawan

I am interfacing two Arduino UNO boards with lora-transmitter and lora-receiver and testing the interconnection by sending "Hello World" which easily is transmizzed to the receiver serial monitor.

But when I connect my sensor to Arduino UNO and interface it with lora-device, then it transmits the sensor value as `int` datatype. So I tried converting `int` to `string` and stored the value in a `unit_8` datatype but it cannot convert the `unit_8` datatype to `string`.

My client code is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>
const int watermeterPin = 2;
volatile int  pulse_frequency;
unsigned int  literperhour;
unsigned long currentTime, loopTime;
byte sensorInterrupt = 0;
RH_RF95 rf95; 
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
   pinMode(watermeterPin, INPUT); 
   attachInterrupt(sensorInterrupt, getFlow, FALLING);
   currentTime = millis();
   loopTime = currentTime;
  while (!Serial) ; 
  if (!rf95.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Sending to rf95_server");
  currentTime = millis();
   if(currentTime >= (loopTime + 1000))
   {
      loopTime = currentTime;
      literperhour = (pulse_frequency * 60 / 7.5);
      pulse_frequency = 0;
       Serial.print(literperhour, DEC);
   Serial.println(" Liter/hour");  
   }
   String str= String(literperhour);
  uint8_t data[] = str;
  rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
  rf95.waitPacketSent();
  uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
  if (rf95.waitAvailableTimeout(3000))
  {   
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
   {
      Serial.print("got reply: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);   
   }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("recv failed");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("No reply, is rf95_server running?");
  }
  delay(400);
}
void getFlow ()
{ 
   pulse_frequency++;
}
```

And my server code is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>
RH_RF95 rf95;
int led = 10;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ;
  if (!rf95.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");  
}
void loop()
{
  if (rf95.available())
  {  
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      Serial.print("got request: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
      uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
      rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
      rf95.waitPacketSent();
      Serial.println("Sent a reply");
       digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("recv failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you using LoRa (node to node) or LoRaWAN (node to gateway to backend)?

Answer (score 0):

`String` is not convertible to a `uint8_t[]`. Because:

> error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

And as such instead of doing this:

```
String str= String(literperhour);
uint8_t data[] = str; // <-- illegal assignment. String is not implicitly convertible to uint8_t
rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
```

Best would be to do this

```
String str= String(literperhour);
uint8_t data[] = str;
rf95.send(str.c_str(), str.length());
```

The [`c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) function returns a `const unsigned char*` (or a similar type) and [`length()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/length/) returns the amount of characters inside the `String`.